# Ubuntu 18.04 with kubuntu /Plasma enable numlock on login

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, login, plasma, numlock

Hi I went through a lot of solutions and tried a couple of them. But till so far no progress.

1. I went through [Activating numlock on bootup - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Activating_numlock_on_bootup) without succes.
2. I installed numlockx `sudo apt install numlockx`. No erorrs.
3. Followed by `sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*s|# Numlock enablen[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] && numlockx onnnexit 0|' /etc/rc.local`

Then I got this error (translated from Dutch into English)

> sed: cannot read /etc/rc.local :file or folder does not exist.

I am looking forward if someone could give me the right command line instruction to enable Numlock on login.

plasmashell 5.12.9

Qt: 5.9.5

KDE Frameworks: 5.44.0

kf5-config: 1.0

Comment: As you've already installed numlockx, and assuming it's installed properly, follow [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) directions and add `/usr/bin/numlockx` as a startup application. Then reboot. You might be able to just log out and login again. Let me know if it works and I'll write up a full answer.

Comment: I follwed the suggested steps

Step 1 Press 'super key'
Step 2 find 'Startup Applications'  via the 'Activities' overview'
I can't find 'Startup Applications'
So I tried the alternative 'you can press Alt+F2 and run the gnome-session-properties command'
I tried to install  the application but I got an error 'installation failed'

Please could you give me direction how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ah, you're using KDE. Your 'autostart' stuff is elsewhere. A quick check (I'm not a KDE user) says to look [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/autostart-programs-on-kde-plasma-5) which is where you'd add the `/usr/bin/numlockx`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all suggestions, I switched off Mouse Keys. and numeric keys worked again. The keyboard layout for English UK is very weird.